# Cannot extract videoURL from MediaRecorder.onstop()

Tags: reactjs, electron, mediarecorder

Many thanks in advance.

I'm building a screen capture application using Electron (v9.1) and React (MacOS Big Sur).

The application opens a new browser window which updates a 'screenParameters' object in the main process (`CaptureWindowParams`) successfully using BrowserWindow.on event listeners.

(I've also used the screen module in the main process to identify the active screen and update `CaptureWindowParams` which works fine.)

The CaptureWindowsParams object is also successfully received from the main process via IPC.

The specific problem i'm struggling with is that I cannot send the videoURL to the main process after recording using MediaRecorder. (I want to relay the URL to another component for display.)

```
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";
import React, {useState} from "react";

function ImageCapturer(props) {

  const [videoObj, setVideoObj] = useState({})
  
  
  const sendVideoURL = () => {
    ipcRenderer.send("capturer:videoURL", videoObj)
  };

  ipcRenderer.once("main_process:captured_window_params", async (captureWindowParams) => {

    try {

      // Get screens
      let screens = await desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ["screen"] })
      
      // create video stream

      for (screen in screens) {
          
          if (Number(screens[screen].display_id) === captureWindowParams.active_screen_id) {
            try { 
              
              const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: false,
                video: {
                  mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
                    chromeMediaSourceId: screens[screen].id,
                    minWidth: captureWindowParams.active_screen_width,
                    minHeight: captureWindowParams.active_screen_height,
                  },
                },
              });
              
              let chunks = []
              

              // create Media Recorder
              let mediaRecorder = await new MediaRecorder(stream);
              
              console.log(mediaRecorder.state)

              mediaRecorder.start()
              console.log(mediaRecorder.state)

              mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                chunks.push(event.data)
              }

              setTimeout(() => {
                mediaRecorder.stop()
                console.log(mediaRecorder.state)
                }, 3000)

            
               mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
                  let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: 'video/mp4'})
                  let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                  setVideoObj({video_url: videoURL})
                  
                  console.log(videoObj.video_url)
                  // console.log(VideoURL) - works properly
                  } 
                    
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
            }
          }
      }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
  })


  return (
    <div className="image-capturer">
      <div className="capturer-buttons">
        <button onClick={sendVideoURL}>Capture Video</button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            window.close();
          }}
        >
          Close Window
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImageCapturer;
```

The videoURL is being produced as expected after recording (as demonstrated by console.log's of MediaRecorder state and the videoURL), however, whenever I try to update the state or send the videoURL to the main process (via IPC), the object is `undefined`

I've tried to create a global variable and update within the `mediaRecorder.onstop()` function but this also results in the same undefined value.

Q: What am I doing wrong / missing ? Is it just a problem with the scope ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this has very little to do with mediarecorder and all to do with reactjs + electon's ipc and scopes. However, since I can only help with the mediarecorder and I got here reading your question a few notes for free (all unrelated to your issue): `new MediaRecorder` is synchronous, no need to `await` it. The file your recorder did produce here is a `"video/webm"` file, passing the `{ type:'video/mp4'}` to the Blob constructor won't do any good.

Comment: And maybe more related to your issue, (I think it would be the next after you enable passing some data between the contexts), a blob:// URL like your `videoURL` points to data that only exists for the Document that created this URL. So if you are going to pass it to an other process entirely, that other process won't be able to do anything with it. Try to pass the Blob directly instead, or whatever way this setup allows to pass binary data.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Found a protracted solution with `const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer())` which does allow me to send between components. Just got to figure out how to view the video now.